# git folders aren't activated after pushing

Tags: git, github

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'message'
git push origin master
```

After installing Git, I've uploaded my first files.

I made a root folder named 'udemy' and there are sub-folders for sub-projects.

I wanted to upload whole folders into a single repository. But it didn't work.

this was what I did.. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

[image: I firstly uploaded my folders to Github but I can't click each folder and navigate..What should I do?]

Comment: I'm not following. What didn't work? What did you expect, and what actually happened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 6):

Your commands look correct. `git add -A` should recursively add the files and folders assuming you ran it in the correct path from your project (working tree).

***Unless they're empty.*** Please note that Git cannot track *empty folders* and you would have to place some file just to activate it (e.g. `README.md`, `.gitignore`, `.gitkeep`).